"drivers/unix/file_access_unix.cpp:257 - Condition "fwrite(p_src, 1, p_length, f) != p_length" is true." godot error
i am having trouble with godot exporting  when i export it gives me back a .EXE file with no data. the error is
drivers/unix/file_access_unix.cpp:257 - Condition "fwrite(p_src, 1, p_length, f) != p_length" is true.
is there any way of somehow getting past this? i am using a HP linux chromebook. if so, please reach out and reply.
